# Experiences with compiling WordPress using Hip Hop?

Tags: php, facebook

What are you experiences compiling Wordpress using Hip Hop? (

> https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/running-hiphop

)

Specific:

- is this maintainable with upgrades?
- is the performance increase bigger than using alternatives?

update: also interesting: http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/168-Can-NET-make-PHP-run-faster-than-the-official-PHP-implementation.html

Comment: Great question, this is something that's interesting to me as well. There doesn't seem to be a lot of actual experience out there - did you see this post (http://openparallel.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/wordpress-on-hiphop-white-paper/) which seems to suggest that you get a hefty scalability increase with HipHop

Comment: Thanks, interesting read. From all I read until now... why does not everyone use this? Where is the catch?

Comment: More reading seems to indicate that it's fragile - WP updates might cause errors, new plugins might cause errors, so it looks like you need to test rigourously each time you upgrade. Also, the normal things one might do for performance and scaling (caching, APC, nginx, CDN etc) have an equivalently good effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original approach of static compilation in HipHop PHP-to-C++ has been since replaced by [HipHop VM just-in-time compilation](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/speeding-up-php-based-development-with-hiphop-vm/10151170460698920).

Facebook [prominently featured WordPress as example application](http://www.hiphop-php.com/wp/?p=113) and it no longer requires extensive (barely any by now) core edits.

---

**Old answer**

There is quite extensive presentation [Rasmus Lerdorf - PHP Performance](http://about.digg.com/blog/rasmus-lerdorf-php-performance) that uses WP as test subject and covers HipHop among many other things.

The summary I can formulate from that presenation is that HipHop:

- requires WP core edits
- has [limited PHP and libraries compatibility](http://talks.php.net/show/digg/21)
- provides (on vanilla WP install at least) very mild performance gain for the effort it takes to implement. In that presentation compiling with HipHop bumped WP from 28.8 transactions per second [to 33.6](http://talks.php.net/show/digg/20).

I think more common performance improving alternatives (like reverse proxy) can easily outperform that without such downsides.

Answer (score 1):

There is ongoing work on making this possible, reference http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14642 as you can see it keep getting punted to future releases, bit core devs are actively involved in making it happen.

As of WordPress 3.3 one still can't compile directly in HPHP without core edits.

Also worth following: http://huichen.org/en/2010/06/wordpress-three-hardened-by-hphp/ & http://huichen.org/en/2010/06/wordpress-3-benchmark-part-2/ if you're interested in it.